# Guess Look behind caused a blank page on iOS device

Tags: ios, reactjs, regex

I uploaded my react website through github, it works fine on Chrome, Edge on Windows 10 as I expected
but, I found it does not show up on any iOS device. I spent lots of days on searching for relevant information. I have tried many options. since I do not have i device so I actually cannot inspect the problem.

Finally, I came to a possibility based on the fact that iOS does not support lookbehind regular expression
and I realized that I have it somewhere in my code.

Two questions come out. the one is if iOS not supporting lookbehind on one component of the whole react app can cause the blank page rendering. and the other is how to replace the lookbehind regex.
Here is the lookbehind regex.

```
/(?<=[+\-*/])0$/
```

I really hope anyone can help me!
Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: `replace(/([+*\/-])0$/, "$1")`

Comment: I want to extract the zero not the part before zero. can you help me with that?